# How to count Xpath match with android listview in Appium

Tags: appium, robotframework, appium-android

I want to count below element, but actually it counts only the elements that are in the display on screen. So if i have 100 elements I need to scroll down more.  How can I include the others in the count too?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how is your application implemented.
Now, developers usually reuse the resource to display those stuff to avoid wasting resources.
For example, you have below table

```
[index][content]
1-A
2-B
3-C
4-D
5-E
```

When you scroll down, the first element will be disappeared, and developer use that resource to display right behind the last element (or they will use a-buffer-element to display - e.g: index=6)

```
[index][content] - after you scrolled down
2-B
3-C
4-D
5-E
6-F (first resource here - or it is the buffer resource)
```

With that implemented way, you can't use "xpath_count" to count.
Let's try to scroll down (use for loop to count the number of elements in a page - then scroll down and continue counting them)

Comment: May  i have some example please ?